# make bash completion reset on branch switch

Tags: git, bash, git-bash, bash-completion

I have the following problem:

I have set up that the branch I currently reside in, is shown in my command prompt like this:

**"[Current_working_dir] (master)"**

however every time I switch branch I get the following error and the branch isn't refreshed:

```
[work_environment] (master) git checkout test 
M   bash/bashrc
Switched to branch 'test'
[work_environment] (master)
```

My .bashrc looks like the following:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"

# Bash git completion
source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt

#Colored command prompt + minimum view
export PS1="\[\e[0;34m\][\[\e[1;34m\]\W\\[\e[0;34m\]]\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\e[0m\] "
```

could anyone enlighten me about what i'm doing wrong? I cannot seem to find anything regarding this error

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is but I have `export PS1='\[\e[38;5;22m\] \w:\[\e[00;0m\] $(declare -F __git_ps1 &>/dev/null && __git_ps1 "\[\e[1;31m\](%s)\[\e[00;0m\]: ")'` in my .bashrc and it does the job. You can change the colours to taste.

Comment: Modifying yours until it worked left me with `\[\e[0;34m\][\[\e[1;34m\]\W]\[\e[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\e[0m\]`. I think you just had the colour codes mixed up somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I prefer `\w` to `\W` for the pwd as it gives the full path.

Comment: the problem is that when I switch to another branch, the previous branch name is still displayed. It seems like the __git_ps1 does not refresh automatically. If I do source ~/.bashrc then my branch gets refreshed to the correct one

Comment: Both of the examples above update for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the double quotes on this line:

```
export PS1="\[\e[0;34m\][\[\e[1;34m\]\W\\[\e[0;34m\]]\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\e[0m\] "
```

That line is being evaluated *immediately* and `__git_ps1` is being called only once.

Try `echo "$PS1"` to see what I mean.

You want single quotes there. The value of `PS1` is evaluated before it is used so the function will get called correctly at that point (and see the current branch/etc.).

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;34m\][\[\e[1;34m\]\W\\[\e[0;34m\]]\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\e[0m\] '
```

Comment: I've been looking at this for twenty minutes trying to work out why mine worked but his didn't. It finally clicks and you post the answer three seconds earlier. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around your PS1 declaration rather than double quotes. At the moment the variables are evaluated and then set to PS1. You want them to be evaluated everytime PS1 is used.